# gird view is not taking parent full height in Android . How can fill height of view rest of Screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, gridview, android-xml

Grid view is not taking height of parent . I can not set height of Grid View after giving attribute "match_parent"  I can not realize where the problem is .

[image: Here The Image is .]

And My Activity XML code is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SinglePokedexActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.35"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgOfPokeMon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/demo" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>




            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.65"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/teal_200"

                >



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameOfPokeMon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:letterSpacing=".03"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="Name" />



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Type_1_ForPokeMon"
                        style="@style/ButtonLikeTextView"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:letterSpacing=".12"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Type_2_ForPokeMon"
                        style="@style/ButtonLikeTextView"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:letterSpacing=".12" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <!--            Wight Container LinearLayout-->

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/LinearLayoutForHeightWeight"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"

                        >


                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:layout_width="130dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="7dp"
                            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:minWidth="128dp"
                            app:cardBackgroundColor="#531dab"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
                            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/card_view_background"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/pokemonHeight"
                                    style="@style/HeightWeightTextView"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                                    android:textAlignment="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    tools:text="56.6 KG" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                                    android:letterSpacing=".05"
                                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                                    android:text="Height"
                                    android:textAlignment="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!--            Height Container Linear Layout-->
                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/LinearLayoutForHeightWeight"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:layout_width="130dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="7dp"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:minWidth="128dp"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
                            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"

                            >


                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/card_view_background_2"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/pokemonWeight"
                                    style="@style/HeightWeightTextView"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                                    android:textAlignment="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    tools:text="1.8 M" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                                    android:letterSpacing=".05"
                                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                                    android:text="Weight"
                                    android:textAlignment="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
                <!--    Base Stat Showing Text-->




                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:text="Base Stats"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <!--Stats will be from Here -->

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridView_single_pokemon"  <!-- Taking About this Gird View -->
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:numColumns="2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />




            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And Here is the code for Grid Item .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="4dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayOut"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"

            >

            <TextView
                 tools:text="Catagory"
                tools:textColor="@color/black"
                android:id="@+id/stat_catagorty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:letterSpacing=".07"
                android:text="Stat"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                tools:text="12"
                tools:textColor="@color/black"
                android:id="@+id/stat_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:letterSpacing=".07"
                android:text="12"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />



        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:- There are 6 grid-Items but 4 is showing in Image and  when I scroll Over gridView rest 2  grid-Item will appare**

Comment: Did you tried Layout Inspector to see what exactly is there ?

Comment: yup in Layout Inspector , Gird view taking full width of parent but in device it is not taking full width ...